# How to create exe file instead of exe and jre folder

Tags: java, swing, jar, exe

I want to deploy my java application, and I want to make a self-contained .exe that simply requires downloading Mario.exe and double-click to run. I'm wondering if there is a way to "put" the jre folder in the .exe?

All of the jar to exe methods I have tried so far mostly I create a jar, then use Launch4j which results in a zip file containing: `Mario.exe` and a `jre` folder with the JVM embedded, which is required to run the application.

My goal is I want `Mario.exe` to run without the `jre` folder.

[image: folder and exe]

Comment: From JDK14 onwards you can use `jpackage` to build an installer for your application, but note this puts JRE runtime image into the installation as well as EXE which uses it.

Comment: @DuncG But not a full JRE.  A trimmed-down JRE containing only the modules on which the application depends.  Still big, but not as big as a full Java installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because tool like Launch4j is wrapper tool and not actually convert your java bytecode to machine code to run without JRE.
You should check out tool `native-image` of Graalvm JDK, it has free community edition which can install by follows instruction here
https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/docs/getting-started/windows/